# User & roles into a table asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-controls, roles

i got this thing working but however i want to take on a different approach since the table is missing lines when user just have one role. I got 3 roles on the site: User, SuperUser and Admin.

This is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult UserList()
 {
    var userRoles = new List<RolesViewModel>();
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);


    foreach (var user in userStore.Users)
    {
        var r = new RolesViewModel
        {
            UserName = user.UserName
        };
        userRoles.Add(r);
    }

    foreach (var user in userRoles)
    {
        user.RoleNames = userManager.GetRoles(userStore.Users.First(s => s.UserName == user.UserName).Id);
    }

    return View(userRoles);
}
```

This is my RolesViewModel:

```
public class RolesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> RoleNames { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And the view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            Role 1
        </th>
        <th>
            Role 2
        </th>
        <th>
            Role 3
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>

            @foreach (var role in item.RoleNames)
            {               
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => role)
                </td>
            }

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

So in the table where i got Role 1 Role 2 and Role 3 i want to have user superuser and admin with a model for each, but i cant really get it working, how do i accomplish this the best way?

Comment: Not clear what you want the output to be. Do you want additional empty cells when the user only contains 1 or 2 roles?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yea, and i want to be able to decide what cell each role will get put into, so im guessing i need more models etc

Comment: This is what it looks like with current code http://imgur.com/URMGV16

Comment: You will need modify your controller method to populate your Roles property with 3 values (empty strings if the role does not exist) and they will need to be in order.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yea i figured i had to do something like that, just gotta figure out how... im far from good on asp and c# haha, im trying to learn

Comment: Personally I think the UI is a bit odd. Why not just display the headings and have "Yes" or "No" (or a tickbox) in the cells (in which case you would have 3 `bool` properties in the model e.g. `bool HasUserRole`, `bool HasSuperUserRole` etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That was kinda a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you're expecting three specific roles, but your model may include more in the future. Your presentation is not very forward thinking in that regard. Also, there is just far too many ways this structure will break down to answer succinctly. Instead, I'm going to suggest that you restructure your grid and your view model to accommodate.

Change your view model slightly:

```
public class RolesViewModel
{
    public string RoleNames { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Next, a combination of making your data access more efficient and a revision of how your Roles property values are constructed:

```
public ActionResult UserList() {
    var userRoles = new List<RolesViewModel>();
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);


    foreach (var user in userStore.Users)
    {
        var r = new RolesViewModel()
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            RoleNames = string.Join(",", userManager.GetRoles(user.Id))
        };
        userRoles.Add(r);
    }

    return View(userRoles); 
}
```

Then finally a simplification of your grid:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>
        User Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Roles
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.RoleNames)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Lastly, if you must insist on using this structure, here's the same presentation that at least uses a checkbox-style setup:

```
public class RolesViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool UserRole { get; set; }
    public bool SuperUserRole { get; set; }
    public bool AdminRole { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult UserList()
{
    var userRoles = new List<RolesViewModel>();
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);


    foreach (var user in userStore.Users)
    {
        var roles = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        var r = new RolesViewModel()
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            UserRole = roles.Contains("User"),
            SuperUserRole = roles.Contains("SuperUser"),
            AdminRole = roles.Contains("Admin")
        };
        userRoles.Add(r);
    }

    return View(userRoles);
}
    }
}

<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>
        User Name
    </th>
    <th>
        User
    </th>
    <th>
        Super User
    </th>
    <th>
        Admin
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.UserRole)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.SuperUserRole)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.AdminRole)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

For the record, I realize that this controller is a bit ugly in how it grabs each user role with a series of round trips to the data store for each unique user. I'll leave that to the OP to clean up if this even gets used...

Comment: Thank you ill look into it, i think im on my way to solve this in a good way now after some reconsidering

Comment: btw i tried a similar code to the last controller but i get error 'there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first' @S.Brentson

Comment: You should actually just grab the user's roles once within each loop. Without looking at what's under the hood of your user manager, this should avoid the problem.

Comment: oookey, not 100% what u mean by that. however cant i use my controller i had and and go with "@User.IsInRole("User").ToString()" for each role in each td some way, that way i should get true or false... but i understand i cant simply do it like that but is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: The @User property of your controller only refers to the user that is currently logged into the web application. This won't be very helpful and is not appropriate here.

I've modified my answer to refactor the roles lookup. See the "var roles = ...". I've not reconstructed the entire solution, so I cannot test my code and markup, but it should generate a matrix of users with checkboxes for each of the three roles.

Comment: yea i get that, but i really cant get that script working. I have tried several way but i always end up with There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Comment: This is an issue within your data access layer. Can't troubleshoot code that can't be seen. My only suggestion is to try to convert your roles to a list before you build your RolesViewModel(). `var roles = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id).ToList();`